# Update main and second table with a before update trigger for message logging

Tags: postgresql, database-design, trigger, schema, update

I currently have the following testing schema:

```
CREATE TABLE userMessage (
    message_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    creator_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES "User" (id),
    created_at BIGINT NOT NULL,
    modified_at BIGINT NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE userMessageLog (
    message_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    modified_by BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES "User"(id),
    modified_at BIGINT NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,

    foreign key (message_id) references userMessage (message_id)
);
```

Where who created the message, when and it's actual content. Then another table where I keep track of who modified (can be another user) the message, when and the previous content.

I also created the following trigger for when the message is first created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION new_message() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO userMessageLog(message_id, modified_by, modified_at, content) VALUES (NEW.message_id, NEW.creator_id, NEW.created_at, NEW.content);
        RETURN NEW;
    END
    $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER new_message AFTER INSERT ON userMessage FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE new_message();
```

Which works as expected. As soon as something is inserted on `userMessage` a new log entry will appear on `userMessageLog`.

My question is, when the user or another user edits that message, how can I create a trigger and modify the `content`, `modified_at` columns from `userMessage` table and add a new entry to the `userMessageLog`? Is there a more better approach to this schema/trigger design?

My only approach resulted in a failed attempt of creating a trigger on `BEFORE UPDATE` for `userMessage` which would make the entry on `userMessageLog`and then `UPDATE` the `userMessage` table, but that would result in recursive calls because of the trigger and I also have no way of letting it know who modified it for `modified_by` and when it was modified for `modified_at` column.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to add a new entry log for each insert/update operation, you should change userMessageLog's primary key. Otherwise you'll receive an error message due to duplicity.

Then, you can deal with trigger recursion by using: **[pg_trigger_depth()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html)**. You can get some examples in this questions:

- [Prevent recursive trigger in PostgreSQL.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708562/prevent-recursive-trigger-in-postgresql)
- [Or at this fiddle I've set up using your table definitions.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9908f56e66503a1b7e5af9f4e5466955)

Having said that, you can find another questions with some discussions about the use of pg_trigger_depth(), with points for or against of using it. Have a look at the answers of [Evan Carrol](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2639/evan-carroll) and [Erwin Brandstetter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3684/erwin-brandstetter) in this question:

- [Is pg_trigger_depth() bad to use for preventing trigger cascading (recursion)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163142/is-pg-trigger-depth-bad-to-use-for-preventing-trigger-cascading-recursion)

Personally, I'll use a function instead of a trigger.